# How to find out exactly which Promise is the SWF workflow waiting on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

Our SWF workflow waits for multiple signals, timers or internal Promises. I wanted to know if there's a way to figure out exactly what promise is the workflow waiting on.

For future, I am thinking of adding the information/values of such Promises to the @GetState method. But what can be done for current running workflows and if there's a way to find this ?

PS : In the event tab, I can check for signals, but my question is more towards internal Promises that is keeping the SWF waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend relying on thread dump to find out at what point workflow is `blocked`. Search for "thread dump" on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/troubleshooting.html) page.